# Using the SensorManager of Android with VES/VTK

Tags: android, vtk, gyroscope

I'm trying to rotate a virtual camera around an object using the Rotation Vector obtained from the SensorManager.

I found the example which gets a rotation matrix from the event.values array and directly applies it to the opengl camera view. That is exactly what I want to do in my application.

However, I'm using VES/VTK for the rendering and the only modifications allowed by the [vesCamera](http://public.kitware.com/ves-docs/classvesCamera.html) are on its position, focal point and up vectors.

How can I obtain these values from the matrix or quaternion given by the Sensor Manager?